# How to restore a Fat32 filesystem under Linux

Tags: filesystems, mount, usb-drive, data-recovery, hibernate

Here is what happened:

I used the Laptop and accessed some data on my usb stick. Then I closed the Laptop putting the system into sleep mode. The USB-Stick was still plugged in. After the laptop was completely in sleep I removed the Stick (the light was off, so it must have been without power). I woke up the laptop today without the USB-Stick. Now when I re-plug it, the filesystem will not be mounted automatically.

I tried to manually mount it:

```
chi mnt # mount -t vfat /dev/disk/by-id/usb-JetFlash_Transcend_4GB_QTMFKJQQ-0\:0-part1 usb/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       Manchmal liefert das Syslog wertvolle Informationen – versuchen
       Sie  dmesg | tail  oder so
```

Doing a `dmesg | tail` I found the following:

```
FAT-fs (sdb1): bogus number of FAT structure
FAT-fs (sdb1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
```

So I tried to do `fsck.vfat` on the partition of the stick, to see if it can somehow fix it:

```
chi mnt # fsck.vfat /dev/disk/by-id/usb-JetFlash_Transcend_4GB_QTMFKJQQ-0\:0-part1 
dosfsck 3.0.9, 31 Jan 2010, FAT32, LFN
Cluster size is zero.
```

Is there some way to repair the filesystem on the stick using linux tools? I am using gentoo.

Also shouldn't this behavior be considered a bug or at least dangerous? Removing the stick while the system is in sleep mode sounds like a common use-case to me. Also if you remove it, it is very easy to forget to put it back in before you turn the system back on, and I don't think this should kill your file-system like this. I am willing to report this bug, but I don't know which mailing list/bugtracker would be the correct one.

*EDIT*:

[I found some suggestions online](http://www.mycomputingart.com/hardware/z24.recover-sector-problem.html). However if I try this using:

```
dd if=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-JetFlash_Transcend_4GB_QTMFKJQQ-0\:0-part1 of=sector6.bin bs=512 count=1 skip=6 conv=noerror,sync
dd if=sector6.bin of=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-JetFlash_Transcend_4GB_QTMFKJQQ-0\:0-part1 bs=512 count=1 conv=noerror,sync,notrunc
```

I still get the same error afterwards. I also tried using `CHKDSK F: \R \T` under windows as suggested by some posts, but this tool only reports the drive as `RAW` and thus unsuported.

Comment: Most systems are set up to unmount external filesystems before going to sleep, but that's only possible if there are no open files.

Comment: @Gilles: I thought so too. I opened a bug report for Gentoo and it is currently being investigated. The files seem gone though, even with TestDisk and PhotoRec (but I could repair some of them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you do anything to the USB-stick, you should make an image of it:

```
dd bs=4k of=stick.img if=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-JetFlash_Transcend_4GB_QTMFKJQQ-0\:0
```

Then you put your stick safely away and use the stick.img file to do your fiddling, instead of destroying more data.

Are there important files on it? Check http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec for recovery tools. It recovers more than just photo's unlike the name suggests.

Once you have recovered you data, create a new filesystem on the USB-stick as the old can no longer be trusted with your data. (mkfs.vfat)

Comment: Notice that '-part1' indicates you're doing your fiddling on the first partions, not on the whole USB-stick.

Comment: Yes, I have made a backup with the command above. PhotoRec also seems very usable. I just found TestDisk and PhotoRec on some other posting online and will try around now, to see how useable they are for this.

Comment: Or you can use `cat /dev/disk/by-id/usb-JetFlash_Transcend_4GB_QTMFKJQQ-0\:0 >stick.img`, with less risk of a typo, and it's likely to be faster.

Comment: If cat is faster than dd, you probably forgot to specify the blocksize: 'bs=1M' Blocksize is 512B by default, whereas most block devices for disks are 4kB based. Not sure why we teach people to use 'dd', I believe 'cat' is not transparent for binary files on all Unices. I know for a fact that 'dd' is the only accepted way in forensics.

Comment: pardon. Imagine I use dd for making image from my xternal hard.. after that how can I access my data from image?

Comment: Didn't check the article in detail, but I've done something similar like this: http://www.andremiller.net/content/mounting-hard-disk-image-including-partitions-using-linux Better safe than sorry, make a temporary copy of your file for experimenting.