# External hard drive can't be mounted on linux(windows says: Format it)

Tags: linux, mount, windows, fdisk, vfat

I have a hard disk and I can't mount it on linux.

These are information may be helpful:

```
# fdisk -l
  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          63  1250258624   625129281    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)


# mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

# dmesg | tail
[ 4660.000901] FAT-fs (sdb1): utf8 is not a recommended IO charset for FAT filesystems, filesystem will be case sensitive!
[ 4660.001309] FAT-fs (sdb1): bogus number of FAT structure
[ 4660.001315] FAT-fs (sdb1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem

#  lsblk -a
.
.
.
loop7    7:7    0         0 loop 
sdb      8:16   0 596.2G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 596.2G  0 part
```

I want to mount it with linux without formatting the external hard drive

Comment: It is possible that the flag that `fdisk` depends on for filesystem type is wrong.  Try: `mount -t auto /dev/sdb1 /mnt/`.  This will attempt all known types until one succeeds.

Comment: The output is:`mount: you must specify the filesystem type`...

Comment: Please help me over http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34920/how-to-restore-a-fat32-filesystem-under-linux

Comment: @MortezaLSC if you hard drive is not already formatted, then format it. You can do so in Windows as well as a Linux system.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha I dont want to format it..first I want to have my data... have you seen the link? help me what can I do after getting image?

Comment: Can you hop into the chat room, please? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux

Comment: I havn't sen chatroom

Comment: Hmmm....I've seen this question before.  As I suggested in the previous post, connect this disk to a windows machine and try to run a chkdsk /x /f x:.  Prior to that make a disk image backup.  Repairing a broken NTFS disk on a Linux system is not really the way to work.